# woocommerce: how to add data obtained from remote server to an item after payment completed?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

### Context

We're selling digital-only products.

Each sold item need a new univoque product key, where key depends on the item itself

### Goal

User buys an item on a store

After paying, but before woocommerce send email to the user, woocommerce ask our server the token sending items details.

The product key of each item is saved into item details

Email will be sent to user with product keys for each items

### What I am already able to do

I did some experiments using

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'so_payment_complete' );
```

I am already able to

- obtain the order instance
- obtain the order items
- foreach order item

  - get the WC_Product
  - extract needed WC_Product_Attribute
  - dialogue with our api server using `wp_remote_post`

Actually I've the 90% of work done.

### What I don't know how to do

I need to store into the order items's data the product key received from our api server.

So my question is splitted in two parts:

- which actions or filters to use instead of `woocommerce_order_status_changed`? I need something that is fired after order is paid but before user receive its order detail mail
- how to set the product key into each order items, I really cannot find the appropriate method in the woocommerce documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to be before e-mail submission try the action `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#401-403

---

and you can save the key on a meta value like that :

```
foreach ($order->get_items("line_item") as $id_line_item => $item) {

    // ...

    update_post_meta($id_line_item, "product_key", $product_key);


}
```

and then you can read it like that :

```
$product_key = get_post_meta($id_line_item, "product_key", TRUE);
```

Comment: Thanks. But what does `get_items("line_item")` vs `get_items()` ?

Comment: `line_item` is the default value but this method can retrieve taxes lines, shipping lines, etc. https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#688-731